# .htaccess route all except if contains word

Tags: php, .htaccess

So at the moment, any missing pages (404) get redirected to domain.com/search.php and carries the query parameters

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ search.php [QSA,L]
```

This works great, however, I have an edge case for domain.com/submit where I need it to redirect to domain.com/submit.php

Can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#rewrite /submit to /submit.php
RewriteRule ^submit/?$ submit.php [L,NC]
#rewrite other non-existent URIs to /search.pho    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ search.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this, I suggest adding NC so it's case-insensitive:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^submit?$ submit.php [NC, L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ search.php [NC, QSA,L]
```